# 'Facebook.JsonObject' does not contain a definition for 'name' ERROR

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I've just installed the facebook c# sdk, but when I'm tring to run the example (after all chenges done in the web.config) I'm receiving this error messgae:

```
'Facebook.JsonObject' does not contain a definition for 'name'
```

**the code is:**

```
Line 31:         var fb = new FacebookClient(this.CurrentSession.AccessToken);

Line 32:         dynamic myInfo = fb.Get("me");

Line 33:         lblName.Text = myInfo.name;

Line 34:         pnlHello.Visible = true;
```

**the error is in line 33.**

What I am doing wrong ?

***I've found the sulotion:***

***line 33 should be -> lblName.Text = myInfo["name"];***

Comment: As myInfo is dynamically typed to a JsonObject myInfo.name is the same as myInfo["name"] so your original code should have worked.

Comment: As @el_tone said, this should work. Are you using .Net 4.0? I am not sure how you would get this compile though if you weren't.

Answer (score 3):

Got the reason:

- You probably added Newtonsoft.Json to the Project.
- Reason: Adding the whole library Folder to the Project will show up unsatisfied dependencies to it (because of the JsonNetSerializer.cs file) - you do not want to add this to the project either.